# Trouble with current_user in Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, join

I'm working on a join table called Languages_User, that has and belongs to many Languages and Users. Users was created with the devise gem. I want a form to be filled out, and the user_id to automatically be populated into the Languages_User table. I feel like I have tried everything, and this seems like a simple task, but hopefully someone can give me some insight into what is wrong:

```
class LanguagesUsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @languages_user = LanguagesUser.new
    #@user_id = current_user    
  end

  def create
    if user_signed_in?
      #@user = current_user
      @languages_user = LanguagesUser.new(languages_user_params)
      #@languages_user.language_id = params[:languages_user][:language_id].to_i
      #@user_id = user_id.to_i

      respond_to do |format|
        if @languages_user.save
           format.html { redirect_to @languages_user, notice: 'Proficiency was successfully created.' }
           format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @languages_user }
        else
           format.html { render :new }
           format.json { render json: @languages_user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end

    else
      puts 'You must be logged in'
      redirect_to new_languages_user_path
    end
  end

  private
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def set_languages_user
    @languages_user = LanguagesUser.find(params[:id])
  end

  def languages_user_params
    params.require(:languages_user).permit(:language_id, :level, users_attributes: [:id])
  end
```

And the _form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@languages_user, method: :post) do |f| %>
   <% if @languages_user.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@languages_user.errors.count, "error") %>prohibited this language from being saved:</h2>
        <ul>
          <% @languages_user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
   <% end %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :level %><br>
     <%= f.number_field :level %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.collection_select(:language_id, Language.order('language ASC').all, :id, :language) %><br>
   </div>
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit  %>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

First question here, so forgive me if it's not properly asked :)

Comment: The indention on your first block of code is too warped to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by adding:

```
    @languages_user = LanguagesUser.new(languages_user_params)
    @languages_user.user_id = current_user.id
```

to my controller.